# How to display output from arrays using for loop on Java

Tags: java

`String [] name = {"IIman bt Zulkifli", "Ismaalif b Ismail", "Katherine Kong", "M.Mirunaaleeni", "Khalish b Ismail", "Younis b Ahmad", "Syifa Hani bt Shahizam", "Atiyyah bt Fahmi", "Furqan b Hafizi", "Qarnur Asraf b Ali"};`

```
    for(int no = 1; no<=10; no ++)
    System.out.println(no + ".");

    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    System.out.println(name[i] + " ");
```

this is an example of the output :

1.

2.

3.

4.

5.

6.

7.

8.

9.

10.

IIman bt Zulkifli

Ismaalif b Ismail

Katherine Kong

M.Mirunaaleeni

Khalish b Ismail

Younis b Ahmad

Syifa Hani bt Shahizam

Atiyyah bt Fahmi

Furqan b Hafizi

Qarnur Asraf b Ali

HOW CAN I DISPLAY THE NAMES BESIDE THE NUMBER ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
System.out.println((i+1) +". "+ name[i] );
```

**update**

**Note**: Please ensure name and marks arrays length are equal

```
for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    System.out.println((i+1) +". "+ name[i] +" : " +marks[i] );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    System.out.println( (i+1) + "." + name[i] );
```

should do

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("\d: %s\n", i+1, name[i]);
}
```

Comment: `i` should be `i + 1`.